# Extract Text from string starting from the righ no substring. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a column containing variable names such as

```
UB121216SVC0054
12122016TH10076
UB121216OH10058
```

I want to extract the letters starting from the right.

```
SVC
TH
OH
```

Because the number of letters and numbers varies, I cannot use substring to specify the first and last characters.

How can I go about this?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: What is the exact pattern? Is it `number/character .. SVC .. numbers`? Do they always end with numbers?

Comment: It always end with numbers, doing something with reverse and standard find letter +2 ?

Comment: You say "the number of letters and numbers varies".  It is unclear which letters and numbers are varying in your examples.

Comment: The number of letters can be at the beggining but I am only looking letters at the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for all of your test cases...
It initially trims all the trailing digits then only sub-strings the characters preceding that until a digit is found. Change the @var to any of your test cases.

```
declare @var varchar(50) = ' '

select case when @var is not null and @var <> '' then 
      right(reverse(substring(reverse(@var),PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',reverse(@var)),len(@var) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',reverse(@var)))),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',reverse(reverse(substring(reverse(@var),PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',reverse(@var)),len(@var) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',reverse(@var)))))) - 1)
      else null end
```

**EDIT**

```
declare @var varchar(50) = 'claim_ud   H4748sd115600'

select case 
      when @var is not null and @var <> '' then
            case 
                when  PATINDEX('% %',@var) = 0 then
                right(reverse(substring(reverse(@var),PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',reverse(@var)),len(@var) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',reverse(@var)))),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',reverse(reverse(substring(reverse(@var),PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',reverse(@var)),len(@var) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',reverse(@var)))))) - 1)
                else
                right(reverse(substring(reverse(stuff(@var,PATINDEX('% %',@var),PATINDEX('% %',reverse(@var)) - PATINDEX('% %',@var),1)),PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',reverse(stuff(@var,PATINDEX('% %',@var),PATINDEX('% %',reverse(@var)) - PATINDEX('% %',@var),1))),len(stuff(@var,PATINDEX('% %',@var),PATINDEX('% %',reverse(@var)) - PATINDEX('% %',@var),1)) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',reverse(stuff(@var,PATINDEX('% %',@var),PATINDEX('% %',reverse(@var)) - PATINDEX('% %',@var),1))))),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',reverse(reverse(substring(reverse(stuff(@var,PATINDEX('% %',@var),PATINDEX('% %',reverse(@var)) - PATINDEX('% %',@var),1)),PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',reverse(stuff(@var,PATINDEX('% %',@var),PATINDEX('% %',reverse(@var)) - PATINDEX('% %',@var),1))),len(stuff(@var,PATINDEX('% %',@var),PATINDEX('% %',reverse(@var)) - PATINDEX('% %',@var),1)) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',reverse(stuff(@var,PATINDEX('% %',@var),PATINDEX('% %',reverse(@var)) - PATINDEX('% %',@var),1))))))) - 1)
                end
      else null end
```

Comment: Same prob of Msg 536, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

Comment: what did you try and pass to the var @gizq?

Comment: @gizq this will happen if you don't have ANY letters in the "middle, such as UH234534254325

Comment: there is always a middle value, is the initials of person who creates the line, can be because i Have blank values?

Comment: @gizq i wrapped it in a case to handle the null or blank

Comment: I also added len(@var) > 20 because i have some wrong entered data (because of migration)

Comment: awesome @gizq so it seems to have worked out for you.

Comment: claim_ud 
H4748115600 this value is creating me errors... is a migrations prob

Comment: @gizq i handled spaces in the edit... that should get you started

Answer (score 0):

For the examples that you give, the following code seems like a simple enough solution:

```
select (case when substring(col, 11, 1) between '0' and '9'
             then substring(col, 9, 2)
             else substring(col, 9, 3)
        end)
```

This is assuming that the codes are 2- or 3- characters and always start at the 9th position.

Comment: It works properly but the substring is not always starting at pos 9

Answer (score 0):

Note that this version creates the same basic execution plan as Radu's code (above), but I find it to be much more readable. Comments included.

```
-- Create a testing table
CREATE TABLE #codes (code varchar(32))
GO
INSERT INTO #codes Values ('UB121216SVC0054')
INSERT INTO #codes Values ('12122016TH10076')
INSERT INTO #codes Values ('UB121216OH10058')
GO
-- Get the substring data
SELECT   -- Get the data up to the first non-letter
    Reverse(LEFT(fragment, patindex('%[^A-Za-z]%', fragment)-1)) as substr
FROM (  -- trim the field at the first letter
    SELECT SUBSTRING(rcode, patindex('%[A-Za-z]%', rcode), len(rcode)) as fragment
    FROM (  -- Working with the reversed values
        SELECT reverse(code) as rcode 
        FROM #codes
        ) as ReverseTable
    ) as WorkTable
```

Comment: Note: I tested this with a table containing additional fields and 90k+ rows, and even returning the additional fields, the plan and execution time are the same.